# NSIS onblur or onfocus event equivalent

Tags: nsis

I need to be able to fill out a second text box based on content from another (first) text box, and I need to do it when the first text box loses focus (or when the second text box gains focus).

I am not able to do what I need to do using `OnChange` because it is triggered after every keypress, but the value of the first text box needs to be evaluated only after the user finishes inputting.

How would I do this? There are no `OnBlur` or `OnFocus` event handlers, and the existing ones `OnChange`, `OnClick`, `OnBack`, `OnNotify` can't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think nsDialogs can handle this, you probably have to use the [WndSubclass plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WndSubclass_plug-in):

```
Page Custom MyPage
Page InstFiles

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include WndSubclass.nsh

Var EditName
Var EditNick
Var NickSubProc

Function MyPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 7% 0 77% 12u "Joe Sixpack"
Pop $EditName

${NSD_CreateText} 7% 14u 77% 12u ""
Pop $EditNick
${WndSubclass_Subclass} $EditNick NickSubProc $NickSubProc $NickSubProc

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function NickSubProc
${If} $2 = ${WM_SETFOCUS}
    ${If} $3 = $EditName ; $EditName lost focus?
    ${OrIf} $3 = 0 ; or no previous focus?
        ${NSD_GetText} $EditName $4
        ${If} $4 != ""
            ${NSD_SetText} $EditNick "Foo $4 Bar"
            SendMessage $EditNick ${EM_SETSEL} 0 -1
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```